# Optimizing object code

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I have 27 parts to my object, the first 2 are independent while the rest are just the same thing one after another. I am sure it can be optimized with a loop, however I am not sure how to approach this and if anyone can assist, I would be grateful.

Code below:

```
var BingoData = {Username: username, cardnumber: serial, Cell1: tablecells[0].innerHTML, Cell2: tablecells[1].innerHTML, Cell3: tablecells[2].innerHTML, Cell4: tablecells[3].innerHTML, Cell5: tablecells[4].innerHTML};
```

Comment: Names like `Cell1`, `Cell2`, `Cell3`, etc. beg for an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `Cells` an array and populate it with a `for` loop.

```
var BingoData = {Username: username, cardnumber: serial, Cells: []};

for(let i = 0; i < tablecells.length; i++) {
    BingoData.Cells.push(tablecells[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Cannot upvote this enough. Never, ever, ever use numbers in a variable name. Instead, just use an array.

Comment: Why is `i < 28`? Should it not be less than 25 since I have 25 cells?

Comment: Yep! My typo... I changed it.

Comment: And also what does `let` mean in this case and why to use it?

Comment: You could use `var` instead of `let`. It's a slightly different way to declare a variable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: No, no, no! It should neither be `25` nor `28` but rather `tablecells.length` !

Comment: Good call. But I kinda like your more functional approach in his answer which avoids the loop altogether.

Answer (score 2):

1) Identifiers that start with Capital letters are for constructors only

2) you may use an array for the cells

3) you may map the `tablecells` to their innerHTML property

```
 const bingo = {
   username,
   cardnumber: serial,
   cells: tablecells.map(cell => cell.innerHTML)
};
```